# Jquery scroll to div and show for a particular time and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am looking for execute as following in query-
On document ready event. if a cookie value is 1 then scroll to a particular div and show it for 3 sec then hide and remove the cookie.

here is my juery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($.cookie("messageshow") != null) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.offset-message').offset().top
        }, 1500);

        $(window).scroll( function(){
            var bottom_of_object = $('.offset-message').offset().top + $('.offset-message').outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                $('.offset-message').fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1, display:'block'}, 3000).fadeOut('slow'); 
            }  
        });
    }
});
```

Messge DIV CSS:

```
.offset-message{
    display: none;
    padding: 40px 70px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Seems it not working as expected. Currently the message div (offset-message) blinking many times then hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think fadeIn and animate both affect the opacity value. Also You immediately call the fadeOut method which means there are 3 methods simultaneously changing you opacity value.

This should fix it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie("messageshow") != null) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.offset-message').offset().top
        }, 1500);

        $(window).scroll( function(){
            var bottom_of_object = $('.offset-message').offset().top + $('.offset-message').outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                var sel = $('.offset-message')
                sel.fadeIn('slow');
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    sel.fadeOut('slow');
                    //delete the cookie; 
                }, 3000); 
            }  
        });
    }
});
```